# JavaScript: конфликт двойной и тройной комбинации клавиш

Tags: javascript, html

В этом эксперименте исследуется конфликт двойной и тройной комбинации клавиш (например `alt+t` и `alt+shift+t`). По замыслу, при нажатии `alt+t` должен измениться цвет левого квадрата, а при нажатии `alt+shift+t` - правого. Однако конбинация `alt+t` препятствует срабатыванию `alt+shift+t`, даже при корректной последовательности нажатия клавиш:

(В снипетте почему-то вообще ничего не работает, но в [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94rpctcj/) - заработает после клика мышью на поле результата. Это потому, что используются плавающие фреймы)

```js
let $leftRect =  $('.rec1');
let $rightRect =  $('.rec2');

$leftBtn.on('mousedown', function(){
    $leftRect.css('background', 'DarkCyan');
});

$leftBtn.on('mouseup', function(){
    $leftRect.css('background', '#ff6666');
});


document.onkeydown = function(e){
    if (e.altKey && e.keyCode === 84) { // T    
        $leftRect.css('background', 'DarkCyan');
    }
    else if (e.altKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 84) { // T    
        $rightRect.css('background', 'DarkCyan');
    }
};
```

```css
.rec1{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background:#ff6666;
}

.rec2{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background:#ff6666;
}
```

```html
<div class="rec1"></div>
<div class="rec2"></div>
```

Как убрать этот конфликт?

Решение "поменять `if` и `else if` местами" (если оно вообще работает) не подходит: предполагается, что на практике комбинации клавиш будут неоднократно переопределяться, потому никакой жесткой последовательности быть не должно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас проблема ровно в том, что вы почему-то с порога отвергаете правильное решение.
Именно поменять местами и никак иначе. Вы должны сначала проверять тройные нажатия (в любом порядке), а потом двойные (в любом порядке). Проверка должна быть оформлена простыми блоками `if` (без колбасы `else if`).
Каждый `if` должен включать `return` после выполнения нужного кода.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    if (e.altKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 84) { // T    
        $rightRect.css('background', 'DarkCyan');
        return; 
    }
    // еще тройные блоки...

    if (e.altKey && e.keyCode === 84) { // T    
        $leftRect.css('background', 'DarkCyan');
        return;
    }
    // еще двойные блоки...

};
```