# В каких случаях нужно выполнять проверку через if-else, а в каких - через несколько if?

Tags: javascript

В ответе на мой вопрос [JavaScript: конфликт двойной и тройной комбинации клавиш](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/675798/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88/675800#675800) было обращено внимание, как я выполнял проверку на нажатую комбинацию клавиш:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    if (e.altKey && e.keyCode === 84) { // T    
        $leftRect.css('background', 'DarkCyan');
    }
    else if (e.altKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 84) { // T    
        $rightRect.css('background', 'DarkCyan');
    }
};
```

> Проверка должна быть оформлена простыми блоками if (без колбасы else
>   if). Каждый if должен включать return после выполнения нужного кода.

А теперь вопрос: а почему? В каких случаях следует поступать именно так, а в каких - через один `else if`?

Я также приведу другой пример из своей практики - делегирование обработчика, которое я также выполняю через `else if`:

```
$pageWrapper.on('click', CLICKABLE_ELEMENTS_CSS_CLASS, function(event){

    if ($clickedObj.hasClass(BTN_TYPE_1_CSS_CLASS)) {
        executeActionforBtnType1();
    }
    else if ($clickedObj.hasClass(BTN_TYPE_2_CSS_CLASS)){
        executeActionforBtnType2();
    }
    else if ($clickedObj.hasClass(BTN_TYPE_3_CSS_CLASS)){
        executeActionforBtnType3();
    }

};
```

Comment: какой то не понятный вопрос если вы знаете что делают эти операторы `javascript`.

Comment: @ Razmik Galstyan, если в `if` условие  выполняется, то в `else if` мы не попадаем. Если у нас два `if`, то мы проверка будет в каждом. Но в предыдущем вопросе было предложено в каждый `if` добавить по `return;`. Это немного запутало.

Comment: если у вас есть функция которая возвращает ответ, это значит что если в одном `if` написано `return` то функция завершает работу и возвращает ответ, значит следующие за ним `if` напрасно не будут работать если они не в блоле `else`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разница в том, что выполнение одного из условий даже не попытается проверить остальные в цепочке и, тем более, выполнить блоки.
А несколько отдельных условий дают шанс выполнить несколько подходящих под условие блоков:

```js
let num = 42;

if(num > 10){
  console.info('42 больше 10');
}else if(num < 50){
  console.info('42 меньше 50, но мы этого не увидим :(');
}

console.info('------------');

if(num > 10){
  console.info('42 больше 10');
}
if(num < 50){
  console.info('42 меньше 50, мы это увидим :)');
}
```

---

В случае проверки клавиш даже наоборот лучше `if...else if`, т. к. это убирает необходимость `return` в проверке (и отмене кода ниже проверок).
Автору, вероятно, просто не нравится цепочки (есть такие).
Главное надо проверить в нужном порядке - от 3-х к 2-ум.

Обработчик выглядит нормально (в контексте проверок).

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. А зачем нужно было `return` добавлять в каждый из одиночных `if` из предыдущего вопроса?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, элементарно - чтобы предотвратить дальнейшее исполнение и проверку на 2 клавиши (очевидно, она сработала бы, что не нужно). Но `else if` уберёт эту необходимость и даст возможность продолжить оставшийся код (если нужно).

Comment: Да, насчет else if погорячился) В данном случае с ними код короче Цепочки не люблю, точно)